# how to calculate the expression values per gene for all cells

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, gene-expression

I'm currently working with a seurat object and I'd like to calculate the expression values per gene for all cells within a particular cluster.

I've gone ahead and subsetted the cluster of interest.

```
tumor <- subset(x = data, idents = c("Tumor"), invert = FALSE)
```

How would I calculate the expression values per gene per cell?

```
FindAllMarkers
```

Finds markers (differentially expressed genes) for each of the identity classes in a dataset per ident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Seurat function is needed. In the seurat object "cells", you can access the raw counts or normalized counts using `cells@assays$RNA@counts` (raw counts) or `cells@assays$SCT@data` (SCT normalized data)